# How do we know the Gamma function Γ(n) is ((n-1)!)?

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, factorial, gamma-function

We know that
$$\Gamma(n) \equiv \int_0^{\infty}t^{n-1}e^{-t} \textrm{d}t = (n-1)!$$ 
But this just looks like another formula and I can't see why this would be equal to $(n-1)!$.

Is there a proof that 
$$\Gamma(n)  = (n-1)!$$ ?

I'm not too familiar with the Gamma function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you integrate by parts and find a relation between $\Gamma(n+1)$ and $\Gamma(n)$ ? What is $\Gamma(1)$ ?

Comment: This is one example where the mathematical induction works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ then integrating by parts for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$
$$
\int_{0}^{\epsilon}t^{n}e^{-t}\text{d}t=\left[-e^{-t}t^{n}\right]^{\epsilon}_{0}+\int_{0}^{\epsilon}nt^{n-1}e^{-t}\text{d}t
$$
And $\displaystyle -e^{-\epsilon}\epsilon^{n} \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0$ so when $\epsilon \rightarrow +\infty$ it becomes
$$
\Gamma\left(n+1\right)=n\Gamma\left(n\right)
$$
And
$$
\Gamma\left(1\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t}\text{d}t=1
$$
With  $0!=1$ and $n!=n\left(n-1\right)!$ both expressions satisfies exactly the same induction relations. What is more interesting is that $\Gamma$ satisfies it for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{*+}$.

Comment: I don't think you really _need_ the rigor of taking the limit as a finite $\epsilon$ goes to $\infty$, but it doesn't hurt much. Also, about the "more interesting" part, $\Gamma$ actually satisifies it for negative numbers as well, just not for negative integers. Also, on $\Bbb R^+$, it is the _only_ analytic function $f$ to satisfy 1) $f(x+1) = xf(x)$ for all $x$, 2) $\ln(f(x))$ is convex (this is called _superconvex_), and 3) $f(1) = 1$

Comment: Well, how does one know what function to start with? you used $$\ \int_0^{\infty}t^{n}e^{-t} \textrm{d}t$$ but why this function? why not anything else? Was it just randomly thought of?

Comment: No, this is the result of the work of Daniel Bernoulli, which has been clarified and  interpreted by Euler ( who will discover later the Beta function ). They both worked to conclude about this formula. It's not about random, that's a well known function that has really interesting properties.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give another (non-rigorous) approach, if $|x|\lt1$, then, slipping an infinite sum inside the integral, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\Gamma(n+1)\over n!}x^n=\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_0^\infty{(tx)^n\over n!}\right)e^{-t}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1-x)}dt={1\over1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

and so $\Gamma(n+1)/n!=1$ for all $n$.

To make this rigorous would require justifying two key steps: the interchange $\sum\int=\int\sum$, and the conclusion that $\sum a_nx^n=\sum b_nx^n$ for all $|x|\lt1$ implies $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

[derivation from taken from flammable maths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBo9J.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! Thanks for your contribution. It would be better if you type an answer rather than an image.